# Google chart erroring out when creating pdf out of the html page

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, google-visualization

i am facing this issue while creating the pdf from the html page where google charts are rendering without any issue but when i am creating the pdf out of that html page charts are giving error

i am using abcpdf library to generate the pdf out of html page.

Html page rendering

[image: Html page]

After generating pdf from same html

[image: After generating pdf]

for google chart i am using

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

this issue previously not there with same pdf library pdf was comming perfect.

i want to know is there any updation happend because of this i am facing this issue .

please help me out not able to get the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Could you share your code were you create the pdf?

Comment: you may want to [convert the chart to PNG](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) before generating PDF --> `chart.getImageURI()`

Comment: Hey thanks i tried this thing but still getting same issue , i think when i am trying to create the pdf the chart.draw method is giving issue. but there also i am not sure what exactly happening .